# Sharepoint search alert from term-driven pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, alert, term-store

I'm using Sharepoint 2016's "term-driven pages with friendly urls" feature to return results for specific term-store terms, using a search result page that shows results for the specified term. I'd like to enable alerts on these pages. However, creating an alert using the default search alert button alerts for *all* changes to the site. I would like it to set up alerts only for results tagged with the term used. Is this possible, and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to set alerts in custom scope if you plan to use the OOB [search alert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/enable-search-alerts) function.

SharePoint only provides three change types to set alert on and no other options are available.
You will have to look for custom solutions like event receivers.

Another reference: [SharePoint 2013 Search Alerts, Programmatically!](https://shivabalachandran.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/lightening-up-the-world-on-creating-sharepoint-search-alerts-programmatically/)